# Detect URL changes on Flutter iFrame

Tags: html, flutter, dart, iframe, webview

I am trying to replicate the Webview functionality in my web app with the following code:

```
iframeElement = IFrameElement()
      ..src = checkoutUrl
      ..style.border = 'none'
      ..width = '800'
      ..height = '400'
      ..onChange.listen((event) {
        print("change");
        print(event.currentTarget);
      })
      ..onLoad.listen((Event event) {
        isLoadingPage = false;
      });
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'webpage',
      (int viewId) => iframeElement,
    );
```

My goal is to detect changes in the URL so that I can perform a checkout operation with Paypal.

The issue is that I can't seem to be able to get anything from the listeners, so I fail to redirect successfully to the web app after successful payment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to perform the operation I needed in the following guide: https://itnext.io/flutter-web-razorpay-payment-gateway-integration-792d6e015409

In particular, is possible to listen to some changes in the iFrame, but few details are needed:

1 - Defining `window.onMessage` Dart side

```
window.onMessage.forEach((element) {
          print('Event Received in callback: ${element.data}');
        });
```

2 - Creating an html file containing your script, importing it as src and posting messages to your parent with the following: `window.parent.postMessage("Your data/message","*");`

This specific guide was for RazorPay but I managed to integrate Paypal as well without any issue,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I couldn't solve it this way because as the dart documentation says :

[image]

the only place you can get the url changes and messages is the window which is not accessible if its inside an iFrame, or at least I couldn't find a way to do it. My workaround was to open the link with url_launcher and set a redirect back to my web app.

P.M. Try BodyElement instead of iFrame, then the window option will be available and you can listen to anything going in the element but its has lots of problems with loading pages that's why I decided not to use it in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, could you provide an example usage of the BodyElement? I tried to use it but I can't find any way to set the url